# VBA - web automation - set attribute value or select item with no id

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm really hoping someone can assist me here, I have tried a few solutions but am stuck on this task.

I need to select an object from a table on our intranet, I hope the below terms are correct, I am very new to ie automation.

I have been able to find the innertext of the row with the below method.

Now I need to either click on it, or change the class attribute to "`listTableSelected`"

the only attributes the row has is class, report type, print landscape and report ID.

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkD7d.png)

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub findtableelement()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTml.HTMLDocument

    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://mimslive/Reporting/StandardReports.aspx"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

    ProcessHTMLPage HTMLdoc

End Sub

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTml.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTml.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTml.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTml.IHTMLElement
    Dim class As MSHTml.IHTMLAttributeCollection

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

                For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children

                    If HTMLCell.innerText = "Transaction Orders Details" Then
                        MsgBox "success"
                    End If

                Next HTMLCell

        Next HTMLRow

    Next HTMLTable

End Sub
```

Comment: the link of code you put is not a a java code, It is HTML.

Comment: thanks for the correction, edited.

Comment: look at `getelementsbyclassname` and `.click` or `fireevent("click")`

Comment: thanks for that Nathan, I ended up ditching the For Each HTMLCell and added If HTMLRow.innerText = "Transaction Orders Details" Then HTMLRow.Click